# Data encryption on first boot

Tags: android, security, encryption, android-8.0-oreo

I did some research on data security that Android has in it's implementation FDE and FBE. I have a clear picture on how both work, but I need some help with it.

I was able to encrypt the device with forceencrypt flag, but I have issues with partition that I want to use for keys storage. I'm unable to use foooter of /data because of legacy reasons. So I have to use partition, that is used by some other apps. It has room on it, definitely 16KB that is needed for this.

The problem I experience is the following: I format partition correctly with mkfs.ext4 when I flash the device. tune2fs and df utilities are showing me this. When I start the first boot on it, someone in init process is trying to something with my partition, I'm getting this error in the kernel:

> EXT-fs error (device memblock5): ext_map_block:568: inode #8 block
>    49164: comm jbd2/memblock5: lblock 11 mapped to illegal pblock(length
>    1)
>
> jbd2_journal_bmap: jornal block not found at offset 11 on
>    memblock5-8
>
> Aborting journal on device memblock-8

Options in fstab are the following for that partition :

> rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,nodiratime,noauto_da_alloc,barrier=1 wait

Does anybody know what I need to look for in init to figure out who and what is messing with my partition?
Where can I find explanation for these flags in fstab, or they are the more-less same as flags used for Linux distributions?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions and this looks more like an Android system question. It might be a better fit for [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

Comment: I posted the same on Android, but on those questions they say that there are more end-user questions :)